# GPGError using DejaDub

Tags: gnupg

I perform a DejaDub backup of my home directory every week and this has worked without problems for years now. I upgraded to 20.04 several months ago and the backups continued to work until this week. I perform regular software updates and so suspect one of those has broken DejaDup. This week each time I try and do a backup I get this message:

```
GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: Bad session key
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

I found this suggestion to fix the problem https://superuser.com/questions/984977/duplicity-restore-failing-no-secret-key but it suggests making changes to `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` and `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` but neither of those files are in my `~/.gnupg` directory.

How to repair my DejaDub backup app?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by making a new directory and setting DejaDub to save the backups there. DejaDup then asked me for a new password, asked for confirmation and then performed a first backup.

I don't know if this is a proper fix or why the old directory stopped working. The folder for GnuPG-Keys under "Passwords and Keys" is empty. (before and after the new backup). I will play around a little with restoring from the older backups to see if they still work.